# Laravel 4 Eloquent table join and where clause on multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi I'm using Laravel and Eloquent in order to store users, there profile and there assigned roles. My table structure is as follows;

```
users

id | username | email | password | created_at | updated_at

profiles

id | user_id | firstname | created_at | updated_at 

roles 

id | name 

assigned_roles 

id | user_id | role_id
```

I'm trying to select all users where there role name is equal to admin. But when I do the following I get an empty array:

```
 return \User::with('profile')->join('assigned_roles', function ($join) {
        $join->where('assigned_roles.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
    })->get();
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Also I am using Zizaco Entrust and Confide https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/1.0

Comment: @trincot no that is correct. i have a function in app/models/User.php defining the relationship

Comment: Just to make sure... you have roles defined in "assigned_roles" for your users? If there are no corresponding rows, then no results would be returned.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I don't have a model for this I'm using https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/tree/1.0 but it doesn't have functionality to do this

Comment: ok, but is there any data in "assigned_roles" table?

Comment: yes there is data that table @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: Replace get() with toSql() and paste the query that is generated

Comment: `select * from `users` inner join `assigned_roles` on `assigned_roles`.`user_id` = ? where `users`.`deleted_at` is null` I don't know why i'm doing this what I want is really to select all users where role name is equal to admin, so I don't think joining the user.id and assigned_roles.user_id is correct. Do you know how I can structure my query?

Comment: I do, posting the answer

Comment: use $join->on instead of where. `where` is for checking against a certain value, `on` for the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch users that have **admin** role you need to use Eloquent's **whereHas()** method:

```
$admins = \User::with('profile')
  ->whereHas('assigned_roles', function($query) {
    $query->whereName('admin');
  })
  ->get();
```

I assume you have **assigned_roles** relation defined. If not, add many-to-many relation between your users and roles:

```
public function assigned_roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('\Your\Model\Namespace\Role', 'assigned_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Comment: I get this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::assigned_roles()` I don't have an assigned_roles model. just a table called assigned_roles and the name of the role is saved in the roles table.

Comment: have you defined that relation in your User model? You need to add many-to-many relation between roles and users

Comment: no i haven't. the role name is also saved in the roles table. my db schema is posted in the question :)

Comment: Then define the relation - otherwise Eloquent will have no idea how to link users and their roles. And DB structure is useless if models are not posted as they contain all that Eloquent knows about your models, not the database schema.

Comment: how would I define the eloquent relationship of the schema I have above? sorry its just that I'm confused I've tried a few combos none work. basically a user can have many roles. but this is assigned through assigned_roles which has a user_id and role_id. I've already said user hasOne->('Profile'); any help would be welcomed!

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many here you have example on how to define many-to-many relation. To be honest everything you need to get what you want can be found there

Comment: is it not possible to use two where queries? if i do all users are returned regardless of role?

Comment: this is the sql select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null and (select count(*) from `roles` inner join `assigned_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `assigned_roles`.`role_id` where `assigned_roles`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `name` = ? or `name` = ?) >= 1

Comment: this works better \User::whereHas('assigned_roles', function($query) {
                $query->whereIn('roles.name',['admin', 'client']);
            })
            ->get();

Comment: It does if you want to fetch users that belong to any of those 2 roles. In your question you stated you want to fetch only admin users.